# Отсутствие возможности редактирования, удаления элементов новой формы

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

При создании новой формы создаётся копия предыдущей без возможности удаления или редактирования элементов, как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что за вырвиглазный скрин? как создаете форму? Покажите код формы, которая копируется. и уберите этот адский блюр со скрина, смотреть больно. Для захвата активного окна используйте Alt+PrtScrn

Comment: Создание формы происходит с помощью: Project/Add Windows Form...

Comment: так лучше, в смысле картинок, но код вставлять лучше текстом, не все сюда ходят с толстым и быстрым каналом. На заднем фоне я наблюдаю файл Form.cs, я правильно понимаю что вы в проекте определили собственный класс `Form`?

Comment: Нет, Form - это основная форма, у которой новая форма 'MainForm', копирует все элементы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по скринам, у вас в проекте присутствует собственный класс `Form`. Если это так, то проблема собственно в нем.

Стандартный шаблон формы, создает новый класс, который наследуется от `System.Windows.Forms.Form` и выглядит так:

```
public class partial class SomeName : Form
```

остальное не существенно.

Когда синтаксический анализатор пытается определить где определено имя, он сначала просматривает пространство имен в котором но использовано, и только потом подключенные пространства имен и, как следствие, первым находит ваш собственный класс `Form` от которого новая форма и наследует элементы, которые вы вполне естественно не можете изменить, т.к. наследование строго расширяющее, т.е. удалить что либо унаследованное нельзя.

Решения два:

1. Переименовать класс `Form`, чтобы он не перекрывал `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.
2. В новой форме явно указать наследование от `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

Первый вариант предпочтительнее.

Comment: Вы были абсолютно правы, спасибо вам!